# bsPrefix prop not working for React Bootstrap?

Tags: react-bootstrap

I need to change the base class for the Popover component in React Bootstrap as styles have been set globally for `popover` which are conflicting with a new component Im trying to make.

The doc say the `bsPrefix` prop can do this but it's not working for me. When I pass it to my component the base class doesn't change it just gets rendered out to the DOM

In React:

```
    <Popover id="popover-basic" bsPrefix="find-me">
      {children}
    </Popover>
```

In the DOM:

```
<div id="popover-basic" bsprefix="find-me" role="tooltip" class="fade in popover bottom" style="display: block; top: 202px; left: 590px;">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I had an old version of the library. Updating 0.31.5 to 1.0.0-beta.8 (latest) and it works.

Comment: I am facing same problem but I am having version "react-bootstrap": "^1.2.2",bootstrap": "^4.5.0"